# Typescript - using Record to create dictionaries

Tags: typescript

Here is what I have so far:

```
constructor() {
   type someTypes = 'xyz';
   const translations: Record<someTypes, ITranslation> = {
   [Constants.someConstant]: {key: 'abc', value: 'Value'}
  }
}
interface ITranslation {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
```

I am importing that class into another class, but translations is not visible. Am I getting it right?

Thanks

Update. Here is what I have so far:

```
  export class allTranslations {
     public translations: Record<someTypes, ITranslation>;
     constructor() {
        this.buildTranslations();
     }
     buildTranslations() {
        this.translations = {
           ['category1']: {key: 'Column_CaseID', value: 'Case ID'},
           ['category1']: {key: 'Column_CaseState', value: 'State'}

        }


   }

   type someTypes = 'category1';
```

I was hoping to have records with multiple types and dictionaries of these types. Something like a dictionary of dictionaries. However, when I check translations property in another class I only have the last entry of category1 in there. Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try exporting the interface?

```ts
export interface ITranslation {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
```

Or Try

```ts
export class TranslationsRecord {
    public translations: Record<someTypes, ITranslation>

    constructor() {
        type someTypes = 'xyz';
        this.translations = {
         [Constants.someConstant]: {key: 'abc', value: 'Value'}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It took export but still translations is not available in another class.

Comment: The problem might be you declared `translations` as a member variable in the constructor. It should probably be a class member.

Comment: It won't take public translations: Record<someTypes, ITranslation>  outside of the constructor without defining type someTypes

Comment: After declaring someTypes outside of the class public translations: Record<someTypes, ITranslation> worked fine. But this.translations: Record<someTypes, ITranslation> is not working.

Comment: Sorry my bad `: Record<someTypes, ITranslation>` shouldn't be in the assignment. updated the answer.